# Flag invalid points in time-series data table from plot in R Shiny

Tags: r, shiny

I am trying to build a Shiny App that will do the following:

1. Read a time-series data set from a database (e.g. DateTime, Value, Status), where Status flags whether a point is valid and be plotted
2. Create a time-series plot of that data (with only Status = Valid points showing).
3. Create a data table in the interface showing the data that are being plotted
4. **Allow for the user to review the data in the plot and then "flag out" points by setting the Status in the table to invalid**

Steps 1-3 above I understand how to do, but I'm looking for suggestions on how to implement the 4th step.  Can Shiny have an interactive table where if a user sets the stats flag, it will react and redraw the plot?

The idea here is to make an interactive data cleaning tool for time-series data recorded from an instrument that often will have bad data points in it.

Thanks

Comment: Your post structure and content are great but a small working example that focuses on the 4th point will help you get answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a solution using `library(DT)`.
Type '0' in the 'plot'-column to remove the datapoint from the plot.

```
library(shiny)
library(DT)

shinyApp(
  ui = fluidPage(DTOutput('myTable'),
                 plotOutput("myPlot")),
  server = function(input, output) {
    output$tbl = renderDT(iris,
                          options = list(lengthChange = FALSE),
                          editable = TRUE)

    myData = data.frame(y = 1:10, plot = 1)

    output$myTable = renderDT(myData, selection = 'none', editable = TRUE)

    proxy = dataTableProxy('myTable')

    observeEvent(input$myTable_cell_edit, {
      info = input$myTable_cell_edit
      str(info)
      i = info$row
      j = info$col
      v = info$value
      myData[i, j] <<- DT::coerceValue(v, myData[i, j])
      replaceData(proxy, myData, resetPaging = FALSE)  # important
    })

    output$myPlot <- renderPlot({
      input$myTable_cell_edit
      plot(myData$y[myData$plot > 0], myData$y[myData$plot > 0])
    })

  }
)
```

For further information see [this](https://yihui.shinyapps.io/DT-edit/).